# How can I install an exterior electrical box flush in stucco?

Tags: electrical, stucco

I want to install an exterior light. I have stucco. I read the article [How to Install an Exterior Outlet Box in Stucco](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/install-exterior-outlet-box-stucco-45919.html), but I am concerned with water getting inside ... Is caulking enough?

Comment: @Tester101, right, I meant at preventing water into the wall. Thanks Michael. I am actually installing an exterior light and my question is about the electrical box where the light is going to be installed on. The electrical box looks like this right now:
http://www.selfhelpforums.com/attachment.php?s=486090a20404d89cf0cdc6c643b0bf56&attachmentid=1285&thumb=1&d=1297194846
if I caulk around the electrical box it would look like this
http://www.selfhelpforums.com/attachment.php?s=486090a20404d89cf0cdc6c643b0bf56&attachmentid=1287&thumb=1&d=1297194846
would that be enough?

Comment: Those are pretty defective instructions: they break the true water barrier in a stucco system.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like the caulk is meant to prevent water from getting into the wall, not to prevent water from entering the electrical box. To seal the box, you'll want to use a weatherproof cover with a weatherproof gasket.

[image: Weatherproof Gaskets]

If the box is in an area protected from the weather, you can use a cover that is weatherproof when nothing is plugged in.

[image: Damp Location Cover]

However, if the box is not protected, you'll want to use a cover that is weatherproof even when things are plugged in.

[image: Wet Location cover]

<sub>*In my opinion, it's a good idea to use an "in-use" cover for **all** outdoor receptacles*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

No. Caulking of the external box edge to the stucco is not enough. You need to make sure to use outdoor grade box cover and outlets assembly that has spring loaded waterproof doors over the outlet.